# C#/LINQ/Select Case: Is this a code smell?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have the following code -> something like `Select case using LINQ` -
This is not the actual code [picked from internet]. 
Just trying to show the Select Case concept using LINQ. 
In my code, based on the *conditions* I am creating new List objects

```
Int32[] numbers = new Int32[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 1 };

var numberText =
(
    from n in numbers
    where n > 0
    select new
    {
        Number = n,
        Text = 
        (
            n == 1 ? "One" :
            n == 2 ? "Two" :
            n == 3 ? "Three" : "Unknown"
        )
    }
);
```

But, the page [here](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) says - "Replace condition with polymorphism".

So, the question is whether such kind of implementation is a code smell and should it  ***always*** be strictly avoided ? LINQ seems like an obvious choice while looping through collections and creating new objects conditionally. May be its wrong ?

Comment: But the reference page says to replace a condition with polymorphism if the condition depends on the type. This condition depends the value, not the type so the page doesn't apply.

Comment: Unless you plan to embed the English ASCII representation of the *entire* set of 32-bit signed integers into your code, I'd say that's a pretty bad smell ;) </joking>

Comment: Think about the future, where your conditions grow to like 10 or more. So your switch statements shall grow too much making the linq look ugly and complex.

Comment: It may make easier to read code if you had a function to handle number to words.  You could then use a switch statement.  I'm not sure whether the compiler optimizer would handle it anyway but it may result faster and more compact code rather than the nested conditions.

Comment: @zenwalker: So, whether you are achieving the conditional logic via switch or Linq or if-else --> are all those implementation buggy ? Question is not about LINQ. Question is whether, everytime, all such kind of logic be converted into some form of polymorphic implementation ? Its more of a conceptual OO related question rather than s strict implementation specific one.

Comment: The code smell lies in the switch statement. And i did not meant the problem with LINQ at all. I meant the conditional logic you have added could be made better via inheritance to avoid lengthy conditional logics.

Comment: @zenwalker::Can you post some code with reference to what you are saying please ?

Comment: Hmm.. sure ill come back with an inheritance example but there are some trade offs which you have to consider. I mean not all and for all conditional logics the inheritance is preferred. As Robert suggested in his comments. So in this case i would suggest or personally if i were u, i wud choose dictionary because the conditions and the body is very simple.

Comment: But I am not doing any kind of inheritance [behavior] specific code here. Your comment was on the specific code saying - _"The code smell lies in the switch statement."_

Comment: I do agree that your not doing any inheritance/polymorphism, but the page link which you have linked does suggests you to use polymorphism and inheritance for this logic. Which is what we are talking about here too. Please look at the bird example he has shown and the class diagram too. Again its a recommendation given and not a rule. So choose wisely as i and Robert already said. There are many alternatives.

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal 
As agreed, below is the code which i was talking about earlier.
Hope this shall give you some directions :)
http://pastebin.com/eT1XrvWL 
Please do note that, its just an example. You can do alot refactoring infact like having a factory pattern, etc. 
As already said, choose wisely. :) Lemme know if you need more help. Good day.

Comment: Thanks @zenwalker ! also thanks for letting me know that something like pastebin exists :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundemental difference. LINQ is an API that allows you to query collections (as you have demonstrated in your question). A switch (or other conditional) statement is used to control program flow.

The page you are referring to is talking about refactoring code when you have a lot of conditional statements controlling program flow based on some type - in this case it suggests that you may want to replace all the conditionals with some poly-morphism. So in this case there is a code smell. But using conditionals in a LINQ statement is OK - there are probably many ways to structure your LINQ - some will perform better than others, and some will read better than others, but I would not say using conditionals in LINQ is a code smell.

Comment: But this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @RobertMS::But, whether you are achieving the conditional logic via switch or Linq or if-else --> are all those logic wrong ? Question is not about LINQ. Question is whether everytime, all such kind of logic be converted to a polymorphic implementation ? Its more of a conceptual question rather than an implementation specific one.

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal: I don't think that anybody would advocate replacing any and all conditionals with some polymorphism. Using an If or Swtich is Ok - but there are times when there are other better ways to do things, as your reference in your question points out.

Answer (score 2):

The article you posted is correct, but that article doesn't apply at all to your query example. Conditional statements do have their use.

In the example, the whole method (and possibly the whole object) *changes its behavior based on one single value* of the object (it is even named `_type`, which shows that purpose). That is indeed a case for polymorphysm, in that instead of the field `_type`, you can have different classes representing each type, making such switch statements unnecessary.

But in your case, it's just a conversion from one value to another.
*It doesn't change the behavior of the whole object.*
I could think of implementing some converter that moves the conditional logic out of the query body, but otherwise, the code is fine.

Comment: .... what exactly did you even say... what kind of answer is this? How does this even attempt to answer the question? Lazy... needs much improvement

Comment: @Botz3000:: But, say, based on the condition, what if you are creating new List<string> object ? I am a little confused with this stuff actually.

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal I don't understand what you mean. Would you want to assign it to the property Text? Or return a `List<string>` as part of the result? The article you linked to doesn't say that you must replace all conditional statements with polymorphism. It just shows a good example when it might be appropriate to use polymorphism instead of a conditional. Using conditionals in a query like your example is fine and no code smell.